# Coded UI UITestControlCollection to array

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am presently getting a list of total number of checkboxes in my document, however, I want to select a random one and in order to do that I believe I have to convert my `UITestControlCollection` to an array.

```
MyCheckboxes.SearchProperties[HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.Type] = "checkbox";
UITestControlCollection CheckboxCollection = MyCheckboxes.FindMatchingControls();
```

Can someone guide me as to how I could accomplish this?

Comment: `var yourArray = MyCheckboxes.FindMatchingControls().ToArray();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ToArray` extension method.

```
var yourArray = MyCheckboxes.FindMatchingControls().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't have to convert it to an array, it's already a collection. You just have to create an enumerator and enumerate through it! Use it like so:

```
MyCheckboxes.SearchProperties[HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.Type] = "checkbox";
UITestControlCollection CheckboxCollection = MyCheckboxes.FindMatchingControls();
IEnumerator<UITestControl> CheckboxEnum = CheckboxCollection .GetEnumerator();

int randomNum = new Random().Next(1, CheckboxCollection.Count );   

for(int i = 0; i!=randomNum; i++)
{
    CheckboxEnum.MoveNext();       
}
Mouse.Click(CheckboxEnum.Current)
```